# Customize product card Up-sell on Woocomerce

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I changed the product cards to also show the category and short description of the product but I can't show it in up-sell products.
this is the code i used

```
function category_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <p itemprop="name" class="card product_category_title"><span><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></span></p>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'category_single_product', 25 );
```

```
/**
 * Add the product's short description (excerpt) to the WooCommerce shop/category pages.
 */

function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->get_short_description() ) return; ?>
    <div itemprop="description">
       <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() ) ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description', 5);
```

How can you do to have the same information also in the up-sell card.
I use Wordpress with Divi theme and I noticed that in the page editor the up-sell products code works and shows the description and category but then they are not seen in the frontend.